# Error when applying lsmeans to model

Tags: r, lsmeans

I have a dataset (`data1`) as below:

```
T,D,P,R
1,0,1,1  
2,1,1,3  
3,0,1,7  
1,0,2,2  
2,1,2,3  
3,1,2,7 
1,0,3,1
2,1,3,4
3,1,3,7
1,1,4,1
2,1,4,3 
3,0,4,7
```

To start with, all variables except the response (which is `R`) are specified as factors (so `D`, `T` and `P` are factors). I then fit the model:

```
model1 <- lme(R~D+T,random=~1|P, method="REML",data=data1)
```

Then I want to use `lsmeans` to average across factor levels of `D` and `P`.

To do this I type:

```
lsm_model <- lsmeans(model1,~T)
```

Doing this, I get two error messages:

> "Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
>     undefined columns selected

And

> Error in ref.grid(object = list(modelStruct = list(reStruct = list(Plot = -11.7209195395097)),  : 
>     Perhaps a 'data' or 'params' argument is needed"

Why can't I fit `lsmeans` to this model? I have used `lsmeans` many times without any problems.

Comment: Did your model actually run?  You are missing the tilde in your `random` statement.  Once I get the model working I can't reproduce your errors.

Comment: @aosmith, thank for the notification of the missing tilde. I have edited the question now. Yes, the model works fine (the missing tilde was just a typing mistake in the question).
So you dont get an error message when you apply LSmeans to this model? I have tried to restart R now, but I still get the same error messages as above.

Comment: I can't replicate either.  Make sure your session is clean (no leftover objects)? I have nlme version 3.1-131, lsmeans 2.26-3

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker, I have the same version as you mention. So this should not be an issue.  
In regards to the clean session, do you think I should try to do something more than just restarting R?

Comment: Could you post the results of `sessionInfo()` after running your code?

Comment: make sure your environment is clean (no pre-existing objects; `rm(list=ls())` if necessary)

Comment: also, show us `str(data1)`

Comment: I tried again this morning and now it worked!! This is even though I haven't changed anything in my coding. I still need to solve the problem (finding out what causes the problem) because I have the same problem for another dataset that I also need to run. Regarding this error: 

"Error in `[.data.frame`(tbl, , vars, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected" 

 What does this error refer to?

Comment: @MarcoSandri. Here is the session info:


R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gof_0.9.1        nlme_3.1-131     lsmeans_2.26-3   estimability_1.2

Comment: And the rest that could not fit in the previous comment:

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.10     lattice_0.20-34  codetools_0.2-15 mvtnorm_1.0-5    zoo_1.7-14       MASS_7.3-45     
 [7] grid_3.3.3       plyr_1.8.4       xtable_1.8-2     coda_0.19-1      multcomp_1.4-6   Matrix_1.2-8    
[13] sandwich_2.3-4   splines_3.3.3    TH.data_1.0-8    tools_3.3.3      survival_2.40-1

Comment: I have solved the problem now. It was a matter of that one variable was not perceived to be part of the dataset, even though I had done a similar approach several times where it worked fine. Specifying that the variable was inside the dataset did the job.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? Could you write a short answer, please? I've run into the same issue.

Comment: I created the variable T from another variable (that I here call Y). I initially did this by typing

T<-factor(Dataset$Y)

And I thought that this was ok. However, R did not perceive it to be part of the dataset before I typed

Dataset$T<-factor(Dataset$Y)

Comment: I have the same error but my issue was that I was putting the model formula in quotes, ie, lm("a~b", data=df).